# How can I use operators for object array elements?

Tags: c++, oop

my main problem is I want to check whether an element of that object list is empty or not.

If I use this I dont get any errors.

```
class A;
A *pointer = new A;
pointer = NULL;
```

but I need to do the same thing with object array elements. I get error when I use the code below.

```
    class A;
A* pointer = new A[2];
pointer[0] = NULL;
```

The error is no operator "=" matches these operands. I cant use

```
 if(!ptr[0])
```

either.

Comment: You declared a dynamic array of `A` objects, not of pointers. In the future, it would be easier and more helpful to include the full error text. You assign twice, but don't indicate which assignment failed. Your code example is also too small in that it can't be copied and compiled.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying. `new A...` is not an array of pointers.

Comment: Did you maybe mean `auto pointer = new A*[2];`? An array of 2 `A*`?

Comment: "no operator "=" matches these operands" this is the full error text.

Comment: In the first code you are setting the pointer to object of class A to NULL. In the second one you are assigning null to the first object that is pointed by the pointer.

Comment: @sweenish you are right I didnt paste whole code because It doesnt include main just class header file.

Comment: Doubt it, since it should say what the operands types are. No where did I say "paste all your code." You need to read the [ask] to understand how to ask questions the right way.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can double-click on an error then go to the "Output" pane to see the full error message from the compiler, rather than the summary from the IDE. Edit: moo.

Comment: @panzerschreck (Also sweenish) You're probably using Visual Studio? Visual Studio by default shows an "Error" pane, which shows error _summaries_. If you switch to the "Output" pane, that'll show the full error message.

Comment: "I need to do the same thing with object array elements" Do you?

Comment: The two pieces of code aren't the same. The first one allocates a pointer to an `A`, and then assigns `NULL` to the pointer, leaking the `A` instance. The second one allocates a pointer two two `A` instances, then tries to assign `NULL` to an `A` instance. What did you want the `NULL` assignment to do?

Comment: Aside: `nullptr` is prefered to `NULL`, because you can't mistake it for a number

Comment: @Quentin Yes Im using visual studio. If i double-click it shows the error line and the error line is as I wrote above.

Comment: I understood the difference between array of pointers and array of object. I still dont know how to check whether an element of "object list" is empty or not. ( See the 3rd code block)

Comment: An `A[2]` is an array of two `A`s, not two pointers or two optionals or anything that could be "null" or "empty". It's literally two `A`s side-by-side.

Comment: Perhaps you want to add `explicit operator bool()` and `bool operator !()` to `A`, if there is an appropriate meaning for "an empty `A`"

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing your minds. I understood I have to declare an operator. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For your problem, this can be done

```
A* ptr[10] = {new A} // notice the [] after ptr
```

All other index in ptr will automatically get nullptr. However you can also do

```
ptr[2] = nullptr;
ptr[3] = new A;
```

and ofcourse

```
if(ptr[4] == nullptr){/*Your stuff*/}
```

Comment: Assuming they wanted an array of pointers to A. What they want is currently a mystery.

Comment: Thanks now I understand but my main problem is I want to check whether an element of that object list is empty or not. Like I wrote in the last code line.

Comment: That still depends on if you wanted an array of pointers or not.

Comment: @sweenish: "check if the element is empty" (insomuch as it even makes sense) only really applies to an array of pointers.

Comment: Assuming that's what they actually need. Without some more information on what's really desired, they might just need to overload `operator bool()` for their class as well. Is about whether an A exists, or whether it's in a non-default state? Taking a poorly worded question literally has led me to more headache than resolutions.

Comment: @sweenish I need to create array of objects now. And wanna check an element of it is empty.

Comment: **Objects**, or **pointers to objects**? The distinction matters.

Comment: @panzerschreck can you post the definition of your class please.

Comment: @panzerschreck an object can not be directly compared with `null`. `pointer[0]` in second case of yours is an object not a pointer.

Comment: @sweenish I think I got it. I will overload an operator.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience but I was mean to give you the idea

Answer (score 0):

After reading most of the comments I'm still not 100% sure what you want. If you are looking for a list of objects, where each object can be present or not you can use arrays of pointers, but that's kind of scary in modern C++. The alternative would be a vector of [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

```
// create vector with 2 empty elements
std::vector<std::optional<A>> a(2);
// if a[0] is empty create one
if(!a[0])
    a[0] = A();
//or set to null
a[0] = std::nullopt;
```

Each element can have a value or not and you don't have to mess around with pointers. The alternative would be a vector of [`std::uniqe_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
// create vector with 2 empty elements
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> a(2);
// if a[0] is empty create one
if(!a[0])
    a[0].reset(new A());
// or set it to null 
a[0] = nullptr;
```

Both options will allow you to check wether an element is present or not and most importantly, both options will take care of cleaning up the created objects. Which option is best for which case is up to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Create array of pointers to the object like this

```
A* pointer[2];
```

then

```
 pointer[0] = new A();
pointer[0]=nullptr;
 if(!pointer[0])
```

Comment: I understood this but I cant still understand that why cant I check the element is empty or not. Look at the last code block.

Comment: @panzerschreck what do you mean by the "element is empty or not".

Comment: I want to use a code like:
let objectarray[0] is first element of object array.-
 I want to assign it an object if nothing has assigned yet.---
if( ! objectarray[0]) { .... }   It gives the same error. Doesnt let me use ' ! ' .